# How to add JavaScript code in page header?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please guide how can I add a javascript block to page header at run-time?
I want to link an external js file to header at run time.

Comment: In HTML? Or through some framework? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load a script at run time with jquery you could use the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.org/myscript.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    async: false
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [this page](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript) that explains On Demand Javascript.
Specifically on this function:

```
function ensureUploadScriptIsLoaded() {
   if (self.uploadScript) { // Already exists
     return;
   }
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   script = document.createElement('script');
   script.id = 'uploadScript';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = "upload.js";
   head.appendChild(script);
 }
```

[CommonJS](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=commonjs&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://commonjs.org/&ei=aw25ToTgCIOs-gbwwdijCA&usg=AFQjCNG9nKa9PYc-4zIZZ3kKl-vuvVk75w) also specifies a way to load scripts and the [Dojo Toolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org) implements it.
You should take a look at require function. 
Example: `require(["a/b"], function(b) { ... });`